# Making a map injective by quoetienting by a certain subset.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Take sets $X$ and $Y$ and a map $f:X\to Y$.
Let 
$$A=\{x\in X\;|\; \exists x'\not =x,\; f(x')=f(x)\}$$
Let $$\tilde f:X/A\to Y$$ defined by $$\tilde f([x])=f(x)$$ where $[x]$ denotes the equivalence class of $x$.

we claim that the map $\tilde f$ is injective.
Indeed, if $f([x])=f([y])$ then $f(x)=f(y)$ hence
$x$ and $y$ belong to $A$ so $[x]=[y]$ thus $\tilde f$ is injective.
and this gives a procedure how to make any map injective. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: What do you mean by $X/A$? Smashing $A$ into one point, that is $[x] = A$ for $x \in A$? Then $\tilde f$ may be ill-defined.

Comment: You say "equivalence class", but I don't see any equivalence relations. You can quotient by sets in group theory, but that's only because there is the coset equivalence relation lurking in the background. You should be defining an equivalence relation $\sim$, not this $A$ set. (Hint: $x\sim y\iff f(x)=f(y)$)

Comment: $X/A$ is the set of equivalence classes where $x\sim x'$ if and only if $x=x'$ or $x$ and $x'$ both belong to $A$.

Comment: @palio: Your justification is perfect.

Comment: Then I have the impression that $\bar{f}$ is not well-defined. What if $x,x'\in A$ with $f(x)\neq f(x')$?

Comment: @drhab  It is perfectly well-defined, just think of $X/A$ as $X$ mod the equivalence the  O.P defined in the previous comment.

Comment: @palio: I am sorry about the previous comment, the equivalence you defined is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing $X/A$, we can define a relation $R$ on X such that $x=y$ iff $f(x)=f(y)$

This is an equivalence is very clear.

Show we can talk of $X/R := $ the set of equivalence class of X.

Define, $\tilde{f}:X/R\rightarrow Y$ as $\tilde{f}([x])=f(x)$.

This map is clearly injective. And $X\rightarrow X/R$ there is natural map, you can think of $X/R$ as $X$ mod some subset of $X$.

Abstract Non-Sense: A map fails to be injective when two different element get mapped to a single element. If you want to make the map injective, you need to forcefully make those two different element a single element of the set. Going modulo equivalence does exactly this job.

Comment: This not the relation corresponding with $X/A$. For that you need a function $g$ sending $x$ to $x$ if $x\notin A$ and sending $x$ to $A$ otherwise.

Comment: I already remarked $X/A$ doesn't make sense. At any rate whatever you defined is not going to work. What do you mean by send $x$ to $A$? Send $x$ to which element of $A$?

Comment: Not to an element of $A$ but to $A$ itself. You could also say: sending elements of $A$ all to a unique and fixed $y$ that is not in $A$. The fibre corresponding with $y$ will be set $A$.

Comment: $y\in Y$ there is no question of whether $y$ belongs to $A$ or not. Remember $A$ is not a subset of $Y$. $X$ and $Y$ are two different sets.

Comment: The function $g$ mentioned in my comment is *not* a function $X\rightarrow Y$. It is - let's say -  a function $X\rightarrow Z$ where $A\in Z$ and where $x\in Z$ for every $x\in X-A$. The equivalence relation on $X$ induced by that function will then agree with quotientspace $X/A$.

Answer (score 1):

Your function $\bar f$ is **not well-defined**.

Let $f:\{0,1,2,3\}\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ prescribed by $0,1\mapsto0$ and $2,3\mapsto1$.

From $f(0)=f(1)$ it follows that $0,1\in A$ and from $f(2)=f(3)$ it follows that $2,3\in A$.

Then $A=\{0,1,2,3\}$ so that:

$\bar f(A)=\bar f([0])=f(0)=0$ and $\bar f(A)=\bar f([2])=f(2)=1$

This shows that $\bar f$ is not well-defined.

Comment: Yes, there is a problem. The problem is $X/A$ doesn't make sense. But the way O.P is thinking is the correct way of thinking. Look at my answer.

Comment: @Babai $X/A$ is a singleton here. If is not the quotientspace that is induced by function $f$. These things are messed up in this all.

Comment: I again emphasis again $X/A$ doesn't make sense. So, what the O.P wrote is not technically correct. I just said the O.P has a  correct vague idea of how to make a map injective. But he messed up by writing $X/A$, instead of writing $X$ mod equivalence.

Comment: @Babai "Doesn't make sense" is not the correct expression here. $X/A$ "makes sense" for any subset of $X$. It might be what it is not what the OP had in mind, but that's a different thing.

Comment: @drhab: It doesn’t make sense in terms of what the OP is clearly trying to do -- which is what Babai does in his answer.

Comment: The ultimate goal is to make the given map injective. The correct way to do that is in Babai's answer. The way the OP suggests doing it however is incorrect as has been rightly pointed out by drhab.